# Create a .cer File From the Text of a Certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

From SSL2BUY I have the text for a certificate starting with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" down to "-----END CERTIFICATE-----". There is no download option just an email option (but that person isn't available) how do I convert the encrypted text between the 'begin' and 'end' statements to an actual certificate?

There are also 4 sections within this page; Servers, PKCS7, Root and Intermediate. How do these all interact?

SSL has been a bane of my life for a long time and I need to conquer this once and for all -_-.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use the docs they have for setting this up? https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/install-ssl-certificate-in-apache-and-mod-ssl

Comment: It isn't encrypted. It is Base64-encoded. This is called 'RFC format'. The OpenSSL command can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to inform you that Servers Certificate and PKCS7 Certificate are different formats of certificate.

PKCS7 format certificate is used in java based server like Tomcat and if you are not using Tomcat you can disregard it.

If you are using a server like IIS, cPanel, Apache etc then you will need to install "Server Certificate". You need to paste the certificate in notepad and save it with .cer extension.

- If you are using a windows based server(IIS) then you will need only 1 file to install there which is "server certificate". On Windows based servers, root & intermediate certificates came preinstalled so you can skip that, they are not needed to install again.
- If you are servers like Apache, cPanel, Nginx, Plesk, etc then you need to install the main domain certificate and CABundle(combination of the Root and Intermediate certificate).

Please Note:

- For all leading CA's (Comodo, Digicert and GlobalSign) all the Root and Intermediate certificates are different. Please suggest your product name so I am able to assist in that particular product which Root and Intermediate certificate has to be used.
- Please let me know the server type you are using such as Apache, IIS, cPanel, etc.